# layout with a centered icon and twoTextViews

Tags: android, android-layout

i was trying this code for a layout with an icon and two textviews 
like this :

i tried this code and it didnt work
can you help me with some suggestions .. or a much more simpler code than mine 
thnks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@id/dashboard_tile"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:minHeight="?android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@android:id/icon"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dashboard_tile_image_size"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dashboard_tile_image_margin_end"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dashboard_tile_image_margin_start"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dashboard_tile_image_size"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/list_item_bottom_padding"
            android:paddingEnd="?android:listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/list_item_top_padding">

            <TextView
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                android:id="@android:id/title"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"

            <TextView
                android:id="@android:id/summary"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/badge_icon"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:id="@id/badge"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/list_item_inner_padding"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/dashboard_badge_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/dashboard_badge_text_size"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:background="@color/list_divider_color"
        android:id="@id/tile_divider"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_divider_height"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dashboard_tile_divider_margin_end"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dashboard_tile_divider_margin_start"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hmmmmm... There are so many errors just in the XML that it's hard to decipher the encryption. Please decrypt it for us. Someone please approve the edit, so i can update the XML to make it look readable.

Comment: Based on the layout, why don't you get a card view layout? or even recyclerview?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sRNWMhcE the readable XML (well close to what I think it should be)